# Creating an interface for serializable types in C#?

Tags: c#, interface

In Haskell, we can do something like this:

```
class Binary a where
    encode :: a -> ByteString
    decode :: ByteString -> a

instance Binary Int where
    encode x = ...
    decode bytes = ...
```

This defines an interface `Binary` which `Int` implements. We can now turn `Int`s into arrays of bytes and vice versa. I wish to implement the same in C#, and my first instinct is to create the interface:

```
interface Binary<T> {
    byte[] Encode(T);
    static T Decode(byte[]);
}
```

But this fails, because `Decode` is not allowed to be `static`.

How could I implement this in C# as cleanly as possible?

Note that I don't want a solution which creates an "empty" or partially-initialized `T` and then populates it by calling a non-`static` `Decode`: this would be messy and leave open a window during which usage of the object is a potential source of bugs.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a whole load of serialization infrastructure build into the .NET Framework - are you aware of it and deliberately ignoring it here? If so, why?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I'm deliberately ignoring it in order to learn how to properly implement an interface relatively similar to this one. Serialization is just a simple example others will understand.

Comment: But serialization isn't typical since it deals with object *creation* (the very problem you're facing here) which most interfaces don't have to deal with.

Comment: Specifically, *can't deal with*, since you can only use an object through an interface *after you've created the object* . Interfaces are not the (only) solution here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Mandating how the object is to be created is exactly the problem I want to learn how to solve in C#, so that's why I picked the serialization analogy. Apologies if I should've simply been more direct in the title and text...

Comment: Why would you want Decode to be static anyway?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Other solutions are fine as well, I'm not married to interfaces. What I'd like is some kind of static guarantee that some types `T`, `U` and `V` are creatable from a `byte[]` in a generic way. Interfaces were just my first guess -- I don't know much C#.

Comment: @mikez If it's not static, then it means I first have to create an "empty" `T` before I call its `Decode` method to again create another `T` from a `byte[]`. What happens to the first `T`? I don't want to have to deal with intermediate uninitialized objects, so using `static` was my first guess.

Comment: Oh I see you want this to be an interface on a thing that is serializable, not an interface for a thing that does serialization. The int example threw me off since you wouldn't be able to but IBinary<int> on int itself.

Comment: You're going to have to create something separately from the types you want to serialize, simply because a lot of the types you'd want to serialize cannot be modified, like `Int32` or `String`.

Comment: By the way, I stumbled across [this interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) today. Thought you might like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real way to add *static* method into interface directly, what is possible to do however is either to add this method into extension class or implement it inside the derived class (that's pretty much all we can do with *static* methods) :

But what i'd do in this case (if for some reason i chose not to use standard .Net serialization framework) i'd probably create my own serializer class:

```
interface ISerializer<T> : IDisposable
{
   virtual byte[] Serialize(T instance); 
   virtual T DeSerialize(byte[] stream);
}

Class MySerializer<T> : ISerializer<T>
{
   public override byte[] Serialize(object instance)
   {
      // .. serialization logic
   }

   public override T DeSerialize(byte[] stream)
   {
      // .. deserialization logic
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      // .. dispose all managed resources here
   }
}

class MyClass
{
}
```

Usage :

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
MyClass newInstance = null;    

using(ISerializer<MyClass> serializer = new MySerializer<MyClass>())
{
    bytes[] bytes = serializer.Serialize(instance);    
    newInstance = serializer.DeSerialize(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually end up splitting code like this up into two types - one base class or interface (depending on my needs), usually generic, which represents the actual data, and one static helper class with static and extension methods. In this example, I'd probably do something like this:

```
public interface IBinary<T>
{
    byte[] Encode(); // Alterantive definition as extension method below
}

public static class Binary
{
    public static T Decode<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : IBinary<T>¨
    {
        // deserialization logic here
    }

    // If you want, you can define Encode() as an extension method instead:
    public static byte[] Encode<T, TBinary>(this TBinary binary)
        where TBinary : IBinary<T>
    {
        // serialization logic here
    }
}
```

Now, you'll use this hierarchy by creating a class like this

```
public class BinaryEncodableInteger : IBinary<int>
{
    // must have this if defined in interface,
    // but if defined as extension method you get it for free
    public byte[] Encode()
    {
        // serialization logic here
    }
}
```

and use the class as

```
var binInt = new BinaryEncodableInteger();
var bytes = binInt.Encode();
var decoded = Binary.Decode<BinaryEncodableInteger>(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `interface`s differ too much between C# and Haskell for it to solve this problem in both cases. I would rather use [`implicit operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx). Although they do not offer a generic solution to this problem, as far as I am aware, since they work through static methods too.

I defined a simple `Binary` class, that contains an array of `byte`, as well as conversion operators from and to `int`.

```
class Binary
{
    public Binary(byte[] value)
    {
        this.Value = value.ToArray();
    }

    public byte[] Value { get; private set; }

    // User-defined conversion from Binary to int 
    public static implicit operator int(Binary b)
    {
        return b.Value[0] + (b.Value[1] << 8) + (b.Value[2] << 16) + (b.Value[3] << 24);
    }
    //  User-defined conversion from int to Binary
    public static implicit operator Binary(int i)
    {
        var result = new byte[4];
        result[0] = (byte)(i & 0xFF);
        result[1] = (byte)(i >> 8 & 0xFF);
        result[2] = (byte)(i >> 16 & 0xFF);
        result[3] = (byte)(i >> 24 & 0xFF);

        return new Binary(result);
    }
}
```

With NUnit I can test this as follows:

```
[TestCase(5, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)]
[TestCase(1500, 0xDC, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00)]
public void TestConvert(int i, byte b0, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3)
{
    Binary testBinary = i;
    Assert.AreEqual(b0, testBinary.Value[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(b1, testBinary.Value[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(b2, testBinary.Value[2]);
    Assert.AreEqual(b3, testBinary.Value[3]);

    int testInt = new Binary(new[] { b0, b1, b2, b3 });

    Assert.AreEqual(testInt, i);
}
```

You can go and implement your own specific logic, but this should demonstrate the principle.